# SharePoint 2010 designer page fitting different screen sizes

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am working in SharePoint designer 2010 but as some of our users have wide screens when I have published the page it displays it very small. Is there a way to set this to fit the screen it is been viewed on if you understand what I am trying to do. My screen is a 19 inch monitor and looks ok but some people have a 24 inch monitor and it looks smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the Page content HTML and use % size for width and height.

This way it expand or shrink automatically

Ex

```
<div style="width:100%">
    ...
</div>
```